# haskell getArgs

Tags: haskell

How does getArgs work, I am trying to read in a text file from the terminal which then sends the contents to one of my defined functions. Can someone post an example code to give me an idea of how it works. Thanks.

Comment: The first hit upon google searching "How does Haskell getArgs work": http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tutorials/Programming_Haskell/Argument_handling

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`getArgs` is an `IO` action which produces a list of `String`

```
fmap someFunction $ readFile =<< fmap head getArgs
```

or in Applicative style:

```
someFunction <$> readFile =<< head <$> getArgs
```

Comment: Just a correction, this is actually Point-free syntax preferring `<$>` over `fmap` and if you checkout the definition of `<$>` it is just an infixed `fmap`

Answer (score 4):

`getArgs` gives you a list of command-line arguments (*not* including what C programmers call `argv[0]`, the name of the running binary). So for example, if you compiled your application as `foo` and then executed `foo a b c` on the command-line, then `getArgs` would return `["a", "b", "c"]`.

From your question, I'm not sure whether you're expecting a *filename* on the command-line, or whether you're expecting to *pipe* the data in on standard-in.

If you're after a filename, just take the result from `getArgs` and pass it to `openFile` (or perhaps `readFile`, depending on what you're after).

If you're trying to do piping, you might look at `interact`, which may do what you want.